# dns server time out from external private ip in aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have installed a bind based custom DNS server on the private ip of an aws ec2 (dns-serv, say).
In the VPC, I have updated the DHCP options to point to the custom DNS Server.

In the same VPC, I have created another ec2 (dns-client,say) and configured it to use dns server @ "dns-serv". I am able to execute successful dns queries on dns-serv. but, on dns-client, same query times out.

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> lb1.sg1.socdoor.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

on dns-client, telnet dns-serv 53
works fine.
I dont know what am I missing. appreciate any inputs in this regard.

Note: I have checked the security groups rules. all outbound is open and inbound to dns port is open.

Thanks,

Comment: (Telnet will connect to TCP port 53) Verify if you've opened UDP port 53, both in security group and iptables.

Comment: This is probably a firewall/network issue. In addition to security groups, certain Linux instances come with iptables enabled. This may also be an issue where service does not bind to all devices and can only be accessed via loopback.

Comment: @dusan.bajic, yes telnet is working

Comment: @datasage, I have verified that named is listening on all interfaces of port 53

Comment: @everCurious, telnet is not relevant here. You need to verify 1) UDP 53 is opened in security group 2) UDP 53 is opened in iptables

Comment: @dusan.bajic, you are absolutely correct. my bad. I am oblivious of it that UDP is used as well. Thanks for the info. you could answer it and I shall accept!

Comment: @dusan.bajic another related query. I am unable to set a default dns domain. so, I need to specify FQDN of a m/c to correctly resolve it. Any way to infer it automatically ?

Comment: that is a client side setting, so please post new question (with relevant info about OS/version), but perhaps SU or SF is better place for such question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successful telnet to port 53 does confirm that TCP port 53 is opened in firewall/security group and listening, but for proper DNS operation both TCP and UDP port 53 must be reachable.